# Order by Asc para listar de forma crescente

Tags: php

Preciso alterar a ordem de itens em uma listagem. Que está decrescente e preciso alterar para crescente.

É um código não feito por mim,  mas preciso dar manutenção.

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-noticia-listagem cf" data-rel-evento="noticias" <?php if($noticias_tag) { echo 'style="display: block;"'; } ?> >
  <?php
                                foreach($noticias_tag as $noticia_tag) {
                                    if(trim($noticia_tag['link_direto']) === "" or $noticia_tag['link_direto'] === null) {
                                        $categoria_slug = $noticia_tag['categoria_slug'];
                                        $noticia_slug = $noticia_tag['slug'];
                                        $noticia_id = $noticia_tag['id'];
                                        $link = "/noticias/$categoria_slug/$noticia_slug-$noticia_id";
                                        $target = "";
                                    } else {
                                        $target = "target='_blank'";
                                        $link = $noticia_tag['link_direto'];
                                    }
                            ?>
    <p>
      ​<strong>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" <?php echo $target; ?>>
                                        <?php echo $noticia_tag['titulo']; ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong><br>
      <?php echo $noticia_tag['chamada']; ?>
      <br> Enviada em
      <?php echo datetimetostrd($noticia_tag['data_publicacao']); ?> - <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" <?php echo $target; ?>>Leia mais</a>
    </p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Pelo que entendi, eu preciso criar uma variável que vai pegar toda a **div** que contém a listagem de notícias em **p** e ali order via PHP.

Comment: Pode utilizar a função [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) passando a função que compara elementos do tipo da lista que tem

Comment: Qual é o campo pelo qual você deseja ordernar? Título, data de publicação, autor?

Comment: Talvez fazendo essa alteração no sql de consulta resolveria mais facil seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, não sei se entendi corretamente, você precisa ordenar a **$noticia_tag['titulo']** correto?.
Então você pode ordenar o array antes de inserir na div, o PHP tem algumas funções que fazem isso, se ele já esta em ordem decrescente pode usar a função array_reverse. no caso:

```
$revertido = array_reverse($noticia_tag);
```

Ou reodernar com as funções asort()

asort($noticia_tag);

se não era isso o seu objetivo, desconsidere.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de ordenar o que está dentro da *div*, o **p** no caso.

Answer (score 0):

Crendo que você quer ordenar por data de publicação, a melhor solução é encontrar o código que cria o array `$noticias_tag`, cujos dados provavelmente vêm do banco de dados, e lá na consulta inserir uma cláusula `ORDER BY data_publicacao`.

Dá para fazer isso na *view*, trecho de código que você mostrou, ainda que é um tanto incorreto, não seria ali não o lugar de tratar os dados. Antes de usar as notícias no `foreach($noticias_tag as $noticia_tag)`, ordene assim:

```
function regra_comparacao($a, $b){

    // Presumo que o tipo do dado seja DATETIME mesmo,
    // sem necessidade de conversão, senão converta aqui!
    $a = $a['data_publicacao'];
    $b = $b['data_publicacao'];

    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($noticias_tag, "regra_comparacao");
```

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de ordenar o que está dentro da *div*, o **p** no caso.